# align 3 divs vertically with top div having background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

i've looked and looked and tried many things but just can't seem to get this to work properly, and it's driving me bonkers.

i'm trying to have multiple divs on a page, 100% width, one after the other. the top div has a background image, and its height will change depending on the screen size.

everything works fine using relative positioning until I add the background image, at which point it needs to be absolute positioned and the bottom two divs sit on top of the first div with the image.

can someone please explain / show me how I can get this to work

Comment: Can you please show the relevant HTML and CSS?

Comment: Please provide the current code your struggling with, thanks

Comment: please add some codes